# How to get the batch jobs result

Tags: asyncapexjob, data-synchronization

I hava a simple requirement in my project,i need to pull data from outside service via calling restful api and push salesforce data to outside service with same way.
so,the problem is the data is very large,so i need query or callout batchable.(there are 100 times call out limit)

> #### In the pull process
>
> batch call-out -----> batch save (to sf)
>
> #### In the push process
>
> batch query ----> batch call-out ----> batch update (clear push flag)

so,i need to do like this:

```
//retrive data from outside service via call-out
List<XXJSON_Entity> pull_result = Database.executeBatch(new PullBatch(..));
//convert json entity to sobject
List<SObject> pull_sobjs = XXXHandler.convertSObject(pull_result);
//upsert data
Database.executeBatch(new PullPersistBatch(pull_sobjs));

//query data need to push
List<SObject> push_data   = Database.executeBatch(new PushBatchQuery(...));
//convert sobject to request json entity
List<XXJSON_Entity> push_entity = XXXHandler.convertJSON(push_data);
//execute push action batchable
List<XXJSON_Entity> push_result = Database.executeBatch(new PushBatch(push_entity));
//convert...
List<SObject> push_sobjs = XXXHandler.convert(push_result); 
//clear push flag
Database.executeBatch(new ClearPushFlagBatch(push_result));
```

but there two questions:

#### 1.how to get the Batch Jobs results.

#### 2.how to keep its order.(the job is asynchronous,means non-block)